# Twitter Bootstrap: How to automatically hide dropdown menu after 2 seconds?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Using this snippet as an example, how could I make dropdown hide automatically after mouse cursor has left the dropdown menu area?

Amazon.com is a great example of this. If you mouse over the "Shop by Department", then move your cursor away, and bring it back within ~0.5 seconds, the dropdown menu will still be visible.

**Bootstrap Snippet**: https://bootsnipp.com/snipps/user-preferences-in-nav-bar

I guess I could do a `setTimeout` but then it will hide it, even after I decide to move my cursor back to the dropdown within those 2 seconds. Maybe I could clear the `setTimeout` on mouseOver to overcome this problem?

What do people typically do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another suggestion...

Handle the hover with a function, and inside you have the element, and the event. So you know when you are on mouseenter and when on mouseleave.
You can use the function properties to save the timer, and clear it when you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/jw7Uz/3/

```
var handleHover = function(evObj){
    var $this = $(this);

    if(!$this.hasClass('open')){
        return true;
    }

    if(evObj.type === 'mouseleave'){
        //    on mouseleave...
        handleHover.timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $this.removeClass('open');
        },2000);

    } else if(evObj.type === 'mouseenter'){
        //    on mouseenter...
        if(handleHover.timer){    //    find timer and clear it
            clearTimeout(handleHover.timer);
            delete handleHover.timer;
        }
    }
};


$('#myDropDown').hover(handleHover);
```

Comment: this is perfectly working in firefox, but not working in chrome! any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to attach `var x = setTimeout('hideme()',2000)` on mouseout event and cancel `clearTimeout(x)` on mousein callback